# Problemas con pasar parametros con GET en Volley

Tags: android, php, http, webservice

alquien sabe en el caso de una peticion GET incluir el HasMap() de los paramentros? Pues con la sobreescritura de getParams() me funciona para POST mas no para GET.
Se agradece cualquier sugerencia. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un bug histórico de Volley, para usar get GET vas a tener que extender request o incluirlos directamente en la URL. Pero es un problema en la implementación de Volley.

Algunos ejemplos de como resolverlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters

Comment: Gracias @jirungaray, opté al final por hacer casi todas las peticiones POST. Demasiado problema los GET y sus parámetros.